# Why does my iPad screen feel sticky?

Tags: ipad, touchscreen

Lately, I've noticed that my iPad's touch screen feels sticky to touch which makes it difficult to swipe in a smooth motion (particular when several swipes in quick succession have to be done in quick succession). As I don't use a screen protector, I initially suspected that this could be due to the build up of oils on the screen but wiping the screen with a microfiber cloth (even with a damp one) does little to help the problem.

The device is 4 months old at the time of writing; the screen should still be in reasonable shape. What could be the problem here and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are cleaning kits targeted for the iPad that might give you a better result than just a damp cloth. I personally bought the Hama Premium Cleaning Kit for iPad and I'm quite happy about it.

The second parameter in the equation are ofcourse your hands, the dryness/greasiness of your fingers will influence the comfort of the moment. Personally, I've found that just after washing my hands I feel some resistance when swiping the screen, and it works best with a more natural greasiness.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this is particularly a problem on **very** hot and humid days. The touchscreen reverts to the smooth user experience that on is used to in cooler, dryer situations.

For people who live in countries where hot and humid weather is normal (like me!), I'd say the only solution would be to use a nice and safe screen protector on top of the touchscreen for a consistent touch experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use a screen protector to mitigate the problem, I would suggest using a good matte/anti-glare one. In my experience, the glossy screen protectors (especially cheap ones) will make your fingers stick even worse than on a bare screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, i hear u. Trick I use especially after washing hands and w/ humide weather in Hawaii is to rub your nose (a naturally greasy location on most people faces) with your thumb and finger you use. Once is usually all thats needed, but sometimes a second dose helps. Korl_B

Answer (score 0):

I use CalClear deluxe cleaning kit and it is used for numerous items such as glasses, iPads, TVs, computers, etc and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I mainly use a stylus, I found after awhile this got sticky, until I tried a silicone lubricant spray. It comes in a handy spray can and is readily available from any hardware store.

Mine is WD40, but there are many brands available and many uses for it.

Don't spray it directly onto the screen, just a little on your finger and rub evenly over the whole screen.

Answer (score -2):

Just make sure that all your fingers are dry while using iPad.